# Max line length for u-boot setenv?

Tags: shell-script, u-boot

I have a line in my u-boot script that looks like:

```
# set default Linux kernel boot parameters
setenv bootargs console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootfstype=ext4 earlyprintk rootwait uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id="generic-uio" fsck.mode=force fsck.repair=yes
```

What is the maximum line length to set a u-boot variable with setenv? I have seen long lines quoted before, and I would like to know what is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered on StackOverflow, but is applicable here --- [What is the maximum byte size for 1 U-Boot environment variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508201/what-is-the-maximum-byte-size-for-1-u-boot-environment-variable), namely [Tom Rini's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6046607/tom-rini) [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40510481/4957508), which says:

> It depends slightly on what you're doing. The overall environment is limited to CONFIG_ENV_SIZE. The amount of text you can input at a given time is CONFIG_SYS_CBSIZE.